# Insert into tbl on Duplicate key update error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query that I want to amend into an INSERT into tbl if it doesn't exist or UPDATE if it does.

```
$sql = "UPDATE tbldata temperature = ?, temperature_feels = ?, humidity = ?, precipitation = ? WHERE id = ?";
```

I am trying the following but have no joy so far - what is wrong with my query below?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbldata (temperature, temperature_feels, humidity, precipitation) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = ?, temperature = ?, temperature_feels = ?, humidity = ?, precipitation = ?";
```

-- update --
This isn't working... what i am doing wrong?

```
       $sql = "INSERT INTO weather_data (uv, weather_status, weather_type, temperature, temperature_feels, humidity, precipitation)
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                uv = ?,
                weather_status = ?,
                weather_type = ?,
                temperature = ?,
                temperature_feels = ?,
                humidity = ?,
                precipitation = ?
                UID = ?";
```

-- update --
my schema

```
'UID', 'char(17)', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, ''
'stationID', 'int(11)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'temperature', 'float', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'UV', 'float', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'temperature_feels', 'float', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'humidity', 'float', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'weather_type', 'int(11)', 'YES', '', '-1', ''
'precipitation', 'float', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'update_station_id', 'tinyint(4)', 'YES', '', '1', ''
'update_due', 'timestamp', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'weather_status', 'varchar(128)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
```

Comment: How would i test this query with binding in my mysql client?

Comment: Please provide the schema for your weather_data table so we can see what primary key and unique indexes you have in place.

Comment: My primary key is the field UID

Comment: Please run `describe weather_data;` and paste the output above.

Comment: see the schema above

Comment: The most likely solution for you will be to use the `values()` function in your `on duplicate key update...` clause, but it's hard to give you a good answer since your example code is incomplete (you don't even supply a value for the primary key) and you haven't shown the error you are getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forget write the `values` here in `insert` query

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbldata (temperature, temperature_feels, humidity,precipitation)  
VALUES (?,?,?,?) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
id = ?, 
temperature = ?,
temperature_feels = ?, 
humidity = ?, 
precipitation = ?";
```

Link for more info http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: sorry.. any ideas what i've done wrong with my amended query above?

Comment: @Zabs hy, you forget to write `values` keyword and its values in embedded query when you use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, you should write insert query with values and at last update field value like above answer